# Oracle Not exists

Tags: oracle

Hi All I have written a query that returns some results based on completions of classes.  I'm having trouble writing an exception report based on the same classes.  I think I need to use a "NOT EXISTS" subquery but am not sure how.

Here is the completions query

```
select papf.employee_number
 , papf.full_name
 , haou.name
 , oe.title
 , oe.course_end_date completed_date
 , oav.version_name
from per_all_people_f papf
 , per_all_assignments_f paaf
 , hr_all_organization_units haou
 , ota_events oe
 , ota_delegate_bookings odb
 , ota_activity_versions oav
where papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
and paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id
and odb.event_id = oe.event_id
and odb.booking_status_type_id in (1006, 1004)
and odb.delegate_person_id = paaf.person_id
and oe.activity_version_id in (3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)
and oe.activity_version_id = oav.activity_version_id
and haou.organization_id = 4729
and trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
and trunc(sysdate) between paaf.effective_start_date and paaf.effective_end_date
order by papf.employee_number;
```

I want to return results for papf.employee_number, papf.full_name,and oav.version_name for employees who have not completed these courses.
So oe.activity_version_id not exists(3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)
I'm kind of confused as to where I should do this?

Thanks

Comment: `So oe.activity_version_id not exists(3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)` - but that explicitly contradicts "and oe.activity_version_id in (3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)". You'll need to come up with a better description of how an activity has COMMENCED but is not COMPLETED

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select papf.employee_number
 , papf.full_name
 , haou.name
 , oe.title
 , oe.course_end_date completed_date
 , oav.version_name
from per_all_people_f papf
 , per_all_assignments_f paaf
 , hr_all_organization_units haou
 , ota_events oe
 , ota_delegate_bookings odb
 , ota_activity_versions oav
where papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
and paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id
and odb.event_id = oe.event_id
and odb.booking_status_type_id in (1006, 1004)
and odb.delegate_person_id = paaf.person_id
/* and oe.activity_version_id in (3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001) */
and NOT EXISTS( 
   SELECT null FROM  ota_events oe1
   WHERE oe1.activity_version_id = oav.activity_version_id
     AND odb.event_id = oe1.event_id
     AND oe1.activity_version_id in (3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)
)
and oe.activity_version_id = oav.activity_version_id
and haou.organization_id = 4729
and trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
and trunc(sysdate) between paaf.effective_start_date and paaf.effective_end_date
order by papf.employee_number;
```

Comment: this query is returning values like using "not in"

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've mentioned (and as user *symcbean* pointed out, to avoid contradicting the logic in the initial SQL), you may need a separate query as shown below to get your results.  Try using NOT IN.

```
select papf.employee_number
 , papf.full_name
 , haou.name
 , oe.title
 , oe.course_end_date completed_date
 , oav.version_name
from per_all_people_f papf
 , per_all_assignments_f paaf
 , hr_all_organization_units haou
 , ota_events oe
 , ota_delegate_bookings odb
 , ota_activity_versions oav
where papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
and paaf.organization_id = haou.organization_id
and odb.event_id = oe.event_id
and odb.booking_status_type_id in (1006, 1004)
and odb.delegate_person_id = paaf.person_id
and oe.activity_version_id NOT IN (3, 1001, 2, 8, 2001)
and oe.activity_version_id = oav.activity_version_id
and haou.organization_id = 4729
and trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
and trunc(sysdate) between paaf.effective_start_date and paaf.effective_end_date
order by papf.employee_number;
```

HTH

Comment: This query shows all training courses other than the ones listed.  Are you talking about doing some type of comparison between the two queries?

Comment: Yes.  Do a comparison and check your results.

Comment: thanks @tale852150 this is what I came up with.  I wrote a query to bring back all employees in the dept. And then used the minus operator against the original query.  I did this for each class in the original query.